# Automating GUI with Win32::GuiTest /other module

Tags: windows, perl, winapi

I have a Win32 Gui Application is there any way with Win32::GuiTest/or any other cpan module  to automate this action : intercepting  the keyboad sent by the user and change it then send it to the application ,if yes could someone show some example ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you are writing a GUI application, you want to keep your view layer as thin as possible, only forwarding events from the GUI framework to the logic-processing code. This allows you to apply traditional unit testing to the logic. MVC and MVP patterns make this separation explicit.